# Using class annotations or static properties

Tags: java, annotations, static-members

I’m fairly new to Java and was wondering about best practices here.

Say I have a generic class (e.g. `Car`), and some inherited classes (`Honda`, `Subaru`) that share some properties.

```
public abstract class Car {
  public static short id;
}

public class Honda extends Car {
  public static final short id = 1;
}

public class Subaru extends Car {
  public static final short id = 2;
}
```

Doesn’t this break the DRY principle? What about using annotation then?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Id {
  public short value();
}

public abstract class Car {
}

@Id(1)
public class Honda extends Car {
}

@Id(2)
public class Subaru extends Car {
}
```

Comment: Neither your `Car` is generic, nor your other classes inherit from it.

Comment: Your classes already have an ID. They are called `Car`, `Honda` and `Subaru`. These names can be retrieved using reflection. The only additional ID you may need is a `serialVersionUID` but that one is specific to a class implementation and therefore does not break DRY principles.

Comment: Note that you cannot inherit `static` members (fields and methods). (OK, the "only additional ID you may need" in previous comment is a overstating it)

Comment: @RohitJain I forgot to extend the classes in my example, my bad.
@owlstead the `id` was just an example, could have been nbSeats. Also, while I understand the example should fail due to inheriting a static member, it seems to run just fine.

What I was asking was: is using annotations OK for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

It is of course a bit a question of taste. I would not recommend that to you.
Annotations are *metainformation* to *mark* fields, methods and classes.
The id (or nbSeats) is rather a field than an annotation.

I would prefer this in your case:

```
public abstract class Car {
  protected static short id;

  public static short getId() {
      return id;
  }
}

class Honda extends Car {
    static {
         id = 1;
    }
}

class Subaru extends Car {
    static {
         id = 2;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry: this solution is deeply flawed :-(
as *Car*, *Honda* and *Subaru* SHARE the same field.
Have a look on that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Honda();
        new Subaru();
        System.out.println(Honda.getId());
        System.out.println(Subaru.getId());
}
```

results in

```
2
2
```

I think this solution might be better:

```
public abstract class Car {
    protected abstract short id();

    public static short getIdOf(Class<? extends Car> carClass)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return carClass.newInstance().id();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(Car.getIdOf(Honda.class));
        System.out.println(Car.getIdOf(Subaru.class));
    }
}

class Honda extends Car {
    protected short id() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Subaru extends Car {
    protected short id() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

It has some advantages:

- It enforces every concrete subclass of *Car* to have an id (by implementing id()).
- It hides the sublasses of *Car* to the super-class *Car*
- The compiler can check that only subclasses of *Car* are passed to getIdOf()
- It enforces the classloader to load the classes (static-initializers are executed only when the class is loaded!)
- many others

It has some disadvantages:

- It needs java reflection
- The id()-method is non-static
- Instances are needed to invoke id()
- It demands a default public constructor in all subclasses
- You can pass abstract subclasses to getIdOf()
- many others

**Keep in mind that the types of the parameters of annotations are limited to only primitive types, String, Class, annotation, enumeration and 1-dimensional arrays!**